# Scheme and defining

Tags: scheme

Define a procedure "and", implementing the Boolean and-function for our procedures true and false - (test (and p q)) should evaluate to true exactly when both p and q are true. Use only function application and lambda expressions.

```
(define (and p q)
   (if eq? p q)
     ((true #t #f)
     ((false) #t #f)))
```

Comment: Define a procedure "Do your own homework".

Comment: This is not a homework. This is from a book resource and I am trying to study by myself. Please do not judge.

Comment: Still, we are not a code writing service. Show us what you have tried and why that didn't work.

Comment: Your syntax is completely incorrect. Do yourself a favor and grab a Scheme book to learn the proper way to write a program!

Comment: "Use only function application and lambda expressions" makes it sound like `if` and `eq?`are out of the question. I suspect that the point of this exercise is to explore how to represent boolean values in the lambda calculus (i.e. `true = λx.λy.x` and `false = λx.λy.y`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that `and` is a special form with different evaluation rules, and we can not truly implement it using just procedures: we need special syntax for it - say, by defining it using a macro. To see this, notice that the built-in special form `and` will *not* raise an error when we do this:

```
(and #f (/ 1 0))
=> #f
```

If we write `and` as a procedure, the above line will result in an error, because the second parameter is in fact evaluated *before* calling the procedure:

```
(and #f (/ 1 0))
=> /: division by zero
```

Now that the above is clear, remember that in Scheme the only false value is `#f`, everything else is considered truthy. With this in mind, a standard `and` special form invoked with two parameters behaves as follows (ignoring the difference in the evaluation rules), notice that the value of the expression is the value of `q`, unless `p` is false:

```
(define (and p q)
  (if (false? p)
      p
      q))
```

But if we want to enforce that only true or false values are returned, we have to change the last line:

```
(define (and p q)
  (if (false? p)
      p
      (not (false? q))))
```

Comment: Why the use of `false?` in the predicate? `(if p q #f)` should work lovely.

Answer (score 0):

A variable `p` is false if it has the value `#f` and it can be used in `if`:

```
(define (and-function p q)
  (if p
      q
      #f))
```

This checks wether `p` is true or not. If it's true the result is `q`. If not the result should be `#f`, the same as `p`.

Know that `and` in Scheme is short circuiting and not a function at all, but I guess you book will come to that.